# Remove Dollar Sign and Decimal Point from Input Post

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have a php form that is for processing payments and I am using js to add a dollar sign and decimal point to the input field. I can't seem to find out how I can then remove the dollar sign and decimal point on submit.

```
$amount = trim($_POST['amount']);

<div class="input-block">
<label for="amount" class="label_comment"><strong>Donation Amount</strong>*</label>
<input type="text" name="amount" value="<?php echo $_POST['amount']; ?>" placeholder="$" data-stripe="amount" id="amount" required="">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.price_format.2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('#amount').priceFormat({
prefix: '$',
centsSeparator: '.',
thousandsSeparator: ','
});
});

</script>
```

Comment: str_repalce() in php would work fine

Comment: `str_replace(array('$', '.', ','), '', $amount);`

Comment: Do you really need to trim the decimal?  what happens to the cents if the decimal is removed?

Comment: I'd guess he's working in cents so that any arithmetic is integer based

Comment: May be smart to do `round(str_replace(array('$', ','), '', $amount) * 100)`. This will remove commas and dollar signs, and then multiply by 100 and round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use the .unmask() function to get the raw value and set in on a hidden input OR reset your formatting in the **onSubmit event**.

```
<form id="yourForm">
  <div class="input-block">
  <label for="amount" class="label_comment"><strong>Donation Amount</strong>*</label>
  <input type="text" name="amount" value="<?php echo $_POST['amount']; ?>" placeholder="$" data-stripe="amount" id="amount" required="">

  <input type="hidden" id="rawAmountField" name="rawAmount" value="" />
</div>
</form>
```

Two changes: a hidden field and the #id argument for the -tag. Then you can add like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#yourForm').submit(function( event ) {

    /* Set the hidden field */
    $('#rawAmountField').value($('#amount).unmask());

    /* OR reset format like */
    $('#amount').priceFormat({
      prefix: '',
      centsSeparator: '.',
      thousandsSeparator: ''
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to handle this would be to use the [filter_input()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) function.  It would work like:

```
$filtered_amount = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'amount', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

That would strip everything from `$_POST['amount']` that isn't a numerical digit.  Of course it requires the use of PHP5.2 or greater.

Answer (score 0):

```
function remove(number) { 

    var tag = number.charAt(0);
    if(tag=='$')
    {
        var res = number.slice(1);
    }
    if(tag!='$')
    {
        var res = number.slice(0);
    }
    document.formname.roundedfield.value = '$'+ parseInt(res); 
}
```